# Change Discord Bot (Python) game or activity

Tags: bots, discord, discord.py

I am trying to repair my Discord Bot and I cannot get any further can someone help me there?

```
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name="<hilfe for help."))
```

The code should change the activity but it does nothing and just gives me a error.
I don't know what to change to get it working.

Comment: Always include your errors in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. It have to be discord.Game not discord.Activity

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('bread'))
```